# Install SQLite Library for LabVIEW 2018 32 bit

Tags: sqlite, labview

I wanted to use SQL with LabVIEW. I searched on the net and found this SQLite Library for LabVIEW. It prompted to download through VIPM(VI Package Manager).But when I'm trying to install, it won't install and the following window is displayed:

[image]

How can I install this package? Can anyone please help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Error 5 is a 'file already open' error in LabVIEW, as [described here](https://support.jki.net/hc/en-us/articles/214135703-Error-5-occurred-at-an-unidentified-location-Error-Message#article-comments), but that specific problem is described as being fixed several versions ago. Are you sure the download was successful and the downloaded package file isn't somehow open in another program or another instance of VIPM? If you still get this problem after a restart, or at least a log out / log in, then I'd ask on lavag.org where the developer is an active participant.

Comment: I am sure that the file is not open in any other program. I restarted my PC and tried it again but with no success. I'd give it a try it in lavag.org. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to run VIPM with admin rights?